# Binding a unit label in WPF textbox

Tags: wpf, binding, string-formatting

I'm binding a pressure to a textbox.  The pressure could be in PSI, KPA, BARS, etc.  I would like to display the unit inside the textbox next to the value.  There doesn't seem to be a way to bind the Units string property in my viewmodel to the StringFormat option of the value binding.  Is there any way to accomplish this without retemplating the textbox?

Comment: You could use another textbox, or a converter, or a MultiBinding+MultiConverter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MultiBinding`:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="Pressure" />
            <Binding Path="Unit"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I played with that and it works great.  However, I assumed my case would be similar to the textbox case, but apparently it's not.  I'm using an extended toolkit NumericUpDown which binds a Value, and not text.  It requires a MultiValueConverter for the MultiBinding.  Sorry for leaving out the important details.