# How can i add a % after a bindin WPF xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="Alcoholpercentage" 
    Binding="{Binding alcoholpercentage,StringFormat=% {0}}" 
    Width="auto"
    />
```

How can i change so that the % is after my binding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758318/binding-a-unit-label-in-wpf-textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put empty curly braces in front of the `{0}`:

```
Binding="{Binding alcoholpercentage,StringFormat={}{0}%}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a value converter.  There are plenty of examples all over the internet.